# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

```
"webpack": "^4.46.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
```

I changed webpack to the above version and getting this error.

```
clean-webpack-plugin: /home/itrus/react/living_goods/build has been removed.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined
```

Stuck in this for a while. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I changed webpack version cause i got the below error initially when removed **node_modules** folder and tried reinstalling it again.

> webpack cli Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the webpack version to the version 4, go to your package.json and look for webpack, in the quotes type "^4.0.0" then run yarn install

Comment: Care to elaborate on why this happens and why downgrading is the solution?

Comment: My scenario consists of two webpack:
```
"@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.14",
```
both marked as webpack4 (version 6, but webpack4). Which one I must change?